# Django Rest Framework can't identify serializer field name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is the problem: I have a serializer field pointing to another serializer. I sending an allright request to server and I get this response:

```
{
    "purchase_header": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

But the field was sended by POST request (in debugger I can see it).

I finded this code in html.py (from DRF):

```
def parse_html_dict(dictionary, prefix=''):
    """
    Used to support dictionary values in HTML forms.

    {
        'profile.username': 'example',
        'profile.email': 'example@example.com',
    }
        -->
    {
        'profile': {
            'username': 'example',
            'email': 'example@example.com'
        }
    }
    """
    ret = MultiValueDict()
    regex = re.compile(r'^%s\.(.+)$' % re.escape(prefix))
    for field in dictionary:
        match = regex.match(field)
        if not match:
            continue
        key = match.groups()[0]
        value = dictionary.getlist(field)
        ret.setlist(key, value)

    return ret
```

Well, when debuging I can see that *prefix* variable contain "purchase_header" and *field* variable contain the same "purchase_header" string but de match fail returning None. Very rare... *dictionary* parameter contain all keys and values.

But If you can helpme I appreciate much.

This is the rest of significant code:

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cancel-requests', PurchaseCancellationsRequestViewSet,
                basename='purchase-cancel-requests')
router.register(r'invoices', PurchaseViewSet, basename='purchase')

urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns += [path('payment-headers/', PaymentHeadersListAPIView.as_view(
    ), name='PaymentHeadersListAPIView')]
```

api.py

```
class PurchaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
        A viewset for viewing and editing purchases instances.
    """
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'list': PurchaseSerializer,
        'create': PurchaseSerializer,
        'retrieve': PurchaseSerializer,
        'update': PurchaseSerializer,
        'partial_update': PurchaseSerializer,
        'destroy': PurchaseSerializer
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        try:
            return self.serializer_action_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return super().get_serializer_class()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()

        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_list_queryset(self):
        try:
            store = Store.objects.get(my_owner=self.request.user)
        except EmptyResultSet as e:
            print("Data Error: {0}".format(e))

        urlquery = self.request.GET.get('cancelled', '')
        cancelled = False
        if urlquery == 'true':
            cancelled = True
        elif urlquery == '':
            # return all
            return Purchase.objects.filter(created_for=store)

        return Purchase.objects.filter(cancelled=cancelled, created_for=store)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_seller:
            raise PermissionDenied(
                detail='Only owners can cancellate Purchases')
        # seller create invoice cancellation request
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['created_by'] = request.user.pk
        print(request.data)
        if request.user.is_owner is True:
            try:
                request.data['created_for'] = Store.objects.get(
                    my_owner=request.user).pk
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return Response(data='User has no Store associated',
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            try:
                request.data['created_for'] = request.user.seller_profile \
                    .my_store.pk
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return Response(data='User has no Store associated',
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # TODO: date ranges
        if self.request.user.is_seller:
            # TODO: Change -> Indeed the seller can get his own created
            #  purchases and refactor this to method
            raise PermissionDenied(
                detail='Only owners can get purchase list.')

        queryset = self.get_list_queryset()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Purchase, PurchaseCancellationRequest, PurchaseHeader


class PurchaseHeaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseHeader
        fields = ['id', 'name']
        extra = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'name': {'read_only': True}
        }


class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    purchase_header = PurchaseHeaderSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ['id', 'cancelled', 'created_at', 'created_by',
                  'created_for', 'pic', 'total_amount', 'purchase_header']
        extra = {
            'cancelled': {'read_only': True},
            'created_at': {'read_only': True},
            'id': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def validate_total_amount(self, value):
        """
        Sanitize the amount value.
        :return: total_amount as float
        """
        total_amount = None
        try:
            total_amount = float(value)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        if total_amount:
            return value
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Exists an error with '
                                              'total_amount value, probably '
                                              'an empty param or bad float '
                                              'format')

    def validate_cancelled(self, value):
        """
            Sanitize the cancelled value.
            :return: cancelled as python boolean
        """
        cancelled = None
        try:
            cancelled = False if value == 'false' else True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        if cancelled:
            return value
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Exists an error with '
                                              'cancelled value, probably an '
                                              'empty param or bad boolean '
                                              'value')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        payment_header_pk = validated_data.pop('purchase_header')
        payment_header_obj = PaymentHeader.objects.get(pk=payment_header_pk)
        purchase_obj = Purchase.objects.create(
            payment_header=payment_header_obj, **validated_data)
        return purchase_obj


class PurchaseCancellationRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseCancellationRequest
        fields = ['purchase']
```

models.py

```
class PurchaseHeader(SoftDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City, through='purchases.ProviderCity')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())


class ProviderCity(SoftDeleteModel):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    purchase_header = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseHeader,
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('city', 'purchase_header')
```

Thank for all friends!!

Comment: Can you share the exact request data your serializer is getting

Comment: Hi! Thank you!

The dictionary from request.POST contains this (from Pycharm debugger):
`<QueryDict: {'created_for': ['3'], 'created_by': ['4'], 'pic': [''], 'total_amount': ['8900'], 'purchase_header': ['4']}>`

If hope that will be enough. Thank you!

Comment: Ok sorry if I did not understand, where was `parse_html_dict` called? What was the `request.data` that you ended up with?

Comment: parse_html_dict() is part of call stack, and is part of DRF code. Examing the code I came to this function. This function recieve a dictionary that really is the request.POST and fail for 'purchase_header' key in regex evaluation...
`regex = re.compile(r'^%s\.(.+)$' % re.escape(prefix))  #prefix is purchase_header string
    for field in dictionary:
        match = regex.match(field)  #  field is purchase_header string too but get None`

Comment: Right, so what did you end up with as `request.data`? Because `request.data` is what is being used by the serializer

Comment: In serializer.__init__ the parameter data (from request.data) is: `<QueryDict: {'created_for': ['3'], 'created_by': ['4'], 'pic': [''], 'total_amount': ['8900'], 'purchase_header': ['4']}>`

Comment: the problem is that dict key not match, for that regex 'purchase_header' !=  'purchase_header'